# Should the weight of the lifting surfaces of an aircraft be deducted from The weight used to calculate the C of G of the aircraft?

Tags: weight, lift

If the aerofoils are creating lift they are doing the work to lift the helicopter. When the helicopter is hovering, the blades are carrying the weight of the entire ship. The forces on the aerofoils are acting in the opposite direction to gravity which is pulling the ship down. These opposing forces create a situation where the ship is now hanging from the aerofoils.

So would this mean that the weight and balance calculation for the pilot should not include the weight of the aerofoils as this weight difference would affect the C of G?

A fixed wing aircraft would suffer the same results?

My question is, should the weight of the section of the aerofoils of an aircraft that provide lift be deducted from the weight used to calculate the C of G of the aircraft?

Comment: Yes, the engineers have already accounted for that in the published tables.  If the CG is in the correct place on the ground in those tables, then the CG will be in the correct (but possibly different) place in flight.

Comment: There is another site, http://aviation.stackexchange.com, that may be more appropriate or useful for aviation-specific questions.

Comment: BowlOfRed thanks for the reply - the tables that are used are plotted using information provided by the maintenance engineers who have weighed the aircraft and calculated the centre of gravity. Even though the table may show that weight and balance is in acceptable limits it could be argued that, if you plot the graph and you find that you are on the limit, the small difference in calculation based on my hypothesis could put you outside of the limit how ever slight it may be.

Comment: Just because the air flow happens to be lifting up on a wing, that doesn't mean that gravity stops pulling down on it.

Answer (score 0):

The aerodynamic lift is defined by the airflow.  It holds the wing up and everything hanging on the wing.

If you replaced a balsa wood wing with a cast iron wing of the same shape, the aerodynamic lift would be unchanged but the weight and balance would change.

Answer (score 0):

The CG of the plane is determined in the static case, where the plane is on the ground and not moving. This necessarily includes the weight of the entire airframe and its wings, payload, crew, and fuel.

The *center of lift* (CL) is determined while the plane is in the air and flying level. Differences in the position of the CG and CL will create *pitching moments* which must be counteracted by changes in *trim* to maintain level flight at constant altitude.